# Discord.py - Check reactions after someone reacts for the 1st time

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

```py
vote_msg = await ctx.send(embed=embed)
    await vote_msg.add_reaction('✅')
    await vote_msg.add_reaction('❎')
    reaction, member = await ctx.bot.wait_for('reaction_add')
    vote_msg = await vote_msg.channel.fetch_message(vote_msg.id) # refetch message
    # default values
    positive = 0
    negative = 0
    for reaction in vote_msg.reactions:
        if reaction.emoji == '✅':
            positive = reaction.count - 1
        elif reaction.emoji == '❎':
            negative = reaction.count - 1
    print(positive)
    print(negative)
```

Currently I have this to refetch the reactions on a message, how can I make it so it will refetch it after someone reacts for the first time, instead of making it wait 5 secs and check?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for the [on_reaction listener](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=on_reaction#discord.on_reaction_add)

You can access all the message reaction from reaction.message.reactions
as follow:

```
@bot.event
async def on_reaction_add(reaction, user):
    reactions = reaction.message.reactions
    # DO WHAT YOU WANT HERE
```